# test/compare the precedence of an operator in Python

Tags: python, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

def has_precedence(op1,op2):

```
opr = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^"]
if op1 == opr[4]:
    return True
else:
    return False
if op1 == opr[3] & op2 != opr[4]:
    return True
else:
    return False
if op1 == opr[2] & op2 != opr[3] & op2 != opr[4]:
    return True
else:
    return False
if op1 == opr[0] & op2 == opr[1]:
    return True
else:
    return False
if op1 == opr[1]:
    return False
else:
    return True

print(has_precedence('/',"-"))
```

i would like to compare two arithmetic operators and return a boolean but unfortunately this method that i did does not work and i am not really sure why

Comment: For starters, `s = +` and `t = *` don't work. At all. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Did you actually compare the *strings* `'+'` and `'*'`?  That would give `s > t`, because `ord("+") == 43` and `ord("*") == 42`, but that's unrelated to operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Python operators are not objects. They are syntax. You cannot refer to them with variables, and you cannot compare them from within Python.

You'd read the [operator precedence documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) instead. Precedence is fixed by the compiler, not a dynamic aspect of the language.

Programming language operator precedence has been largely standardized; Python adheres to the [PEMDAS order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), for example.